# How to Flip the div in time intervals

Tags: html, css

Hi please look at this script and tell me how to flip A B and C divs in time intervals. I want A to flip first then it stops, B flips next and stops, and C next and Back to A, B and C again like in a loop and start it over again. Is this possible in CSS3 ? In this code all the divs flip on the same time.

```css
/* ::: HOLDER, CARD, FACES */
.holder {
  display:     inline-block;
  width:       64px;
  height:      64px;
  perspective: 700px;
}
.card, .front, .back{
  position:   absolute;
  height:     inherit;
  width:      inherit;
  transition: all .7s;
  transform-style:     preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* ::: FACES */
.front{background: tomato;}
.back{background:  slategray;}

/* ::: SETUP FACES */
.flipH .back{transform: rotateY(-180deg);}
.flipV .back{transform: rotateX(180deg);}

/* ::: HOVER EFFECTS (Remove Automated for this to work) */
.flipH:hover .card{ transform: rotateY(180deg); }
.flipV:hover .card{ transform: rotateX(-180deg); }

/* ::: AUTOMATED EFFECTS */
.flipH .card{
  animation: flipH 2s 0s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: flipH 2s 0s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}
.flipV .card{
  animation: flipV 2s 0s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: flipV 2s 0s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes flipH {
  0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipH {
  0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); }
}
@keyframes flipV {
  0% { transform: rotateX(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateX(-180deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipV {
  0% { transform: rotateX(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateX(-180deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="holder flipH">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">A</div>
    <div class="back">A</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="holder flipV">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">B</div>
    <div class="back">B</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="holder flipH">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">C</div>
    <div class="back">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Maddy says, animation delay is the trick

```css
/* ::: HOLDER, CARD, FACES */
.holder {
  display:     inline-block;
  width:       64px;
  height:      64px;
  perspective: 700px;
}
.card, .front, .back{
  position:   absolute;
  height:     inherit;
  width:      inherit;
  transition: all .7s;
  transform-style:     preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* ::: FACES */
.front{background: tomato;}
.back{background:  slategray;}

/* ::: SETUP FACES */
.flipH .back{transform: rotateY(-180deg);}
.flipV .back{transform: rotateX(180deg);}

/* ::: HOVER EFFECTS (Remove Automated for this to work) */
.flipH:hover .card{ transform: rotateY(180deg); }
.flipV:hover .card{ transform: rotateX(-180deg); }

/* ::: AUTOMATED EFFECTS */
.flipH .card{
  animation: flipH 3s 0s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: flipH 3s 0s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}
.flipV .card{
  animation: flipV 3s 1s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: flipV 3s 1s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}
.flipH:nth-child(3) .card {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
@keyframes flipH {
  0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipH {
  0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); }
}
@keyframes flipV {
  0% { transform: rotateX(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateX(-180deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipV {
  0% { transform: rotateX(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateX(-180deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="holder flipH">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">A</div>
    <div class="back">A</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="holder flipV">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">B</div>
    <div class="back">B</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="holder flipH">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">C</div>
    <div class="back">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is in css3 2 type of tag `animation-delay` and `animation-iteration-count`, you need to google for that.

I think you want something like this-

```css
.holder {
  display:     inline-block;
  width:       64px;
  height:      64px;
  perspective: 700px;
}
.card, .front, .back{
  position:   absolute;
  height:     inherit;
  width:      inherit;
  transition: all .7s;
  transform-style:     preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* ::: FACES */
.front{background: tomato;}
.back{background:  slategray;}

/* ::: SETUP FACES */
.flipH .back{transform: rotateY(-180deg);}
.flipV .back{transform: rotateX(180deg);}

/* ::: HOVER EFFECTS (Remove Automated for this to work) */
.flipH:hover .card{ transform: rotateY(180deg); }
.flipV:hover .card{ transform: rotateX(-180deg); }

/* ::: AUTOMATED EFFECTS */
.flipH .card{
  animation: flipH 2s 0s 1 alternate ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: flipH 2s 0s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}
.flipV .card{
  animation: flipV 2s 1s 1 alternate ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: flipV 2s 0s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}
.flipH.flipH2 .card{
      animation: flipH 2s 2s 1 alternate ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: flipH 2s 0s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes flipH {
  0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipH {
  0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); }
}
@keyframes flipV {
  0% { transform: rotateX(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateX(-180deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipV {
  0% { transform: rotateX(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateX(-180deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="holder flipH">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">A</div>
    <div class="back">A</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="holder flipV">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">B</div>
    <div class="back">B</div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="holder flipH flipH2">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">C</div>
    <div class="back">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: Hi, still all the divs flips at the same time. I want A move first then B, finally C.. Should happen constantly like in a loop. I googled them.
1. animation-iteration-count: specifies the number of times an animation should be played.
2. animation-delay: this delays the starting time, but when it runs again and again it doesn't work no!
Thanks any way for trying.