# With CSS animation / transform. How can I flip one div up then back down, Then a second div up and back down with pauses + loop?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a question regarding animation/transform with CSS. I want to flip one div from the bottom as the origin and up and then flip back down. After that, another div flips up then back down again. And repeat this infinitely with pauses between divs so they don't flip up all at the same time.

**Note:** I've tried using animation-delay, and the css animation tricks where you use the 0% {...} 20%, 100% {...} still doesn't seem to work on what and how I wanted it to work.

**Edit:** Heres a js fiddle link regarding what I'm trying to do. This is the problem I'm having. https://jsfiddle.net/9qx0Lnj6/1/

**Quick Update:** Heres a GIF to visually see what I mean and what I try to achieve. https://giphy.com/gifs/ywIkiagNlsm4ux2QSd

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon-wrap">
    <div class="icon-one icon">
        One
    </div>
    <div class="icon-two icon">
        Two
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

`.container {
      position: relative;
      .icon-wrap {
        position: relative;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        overflow:hidden;
        perspective: 1000px;
        .icon {
          position:absolute;
          width:50px;
          height:50px;
        }
        .icon-one {
          background:red;
          transform-origin: bottom;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
          animation: 3s flip 2s infinite linear;
        }
        .icon-two {
          background:blue;
          transform-origin: bottom;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
          animation: 3s flip infinite linear;
        }
      }
    }`

    `@keyframes flip{
                0% {
                transform: rotateX(180deg)
              }
              14% {
                transform: rotateX(0deg);
              }
              100% {
                transform: rotateX(0deg);
              }
    }`
```

Comment: Add  working example

Comment: Just added a working example.

Comment: Just in your code change this: `animation: 3s flip 2s infinite linear` to be  `animation: 5s flip 5s infinite linear`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sLud5tkz/

Comment: I already updated it.

Comment: Yeah, but i want the red to show first then it falls back down. Then blue shows up then fall back down. then red again then blue and so on

Comment: Use `animation-fill-mode` but I don't think your question   explain that:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation-fill-mode

Comment: @RaymondShen try to run the code below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('div');
a = Array.prototype.slice.call(a);

var timings = {
  easing: 'ease-in-out',
  iterations: Infinity,
  direction: 'alternate',
  fill: 'both'
}

a.forEach(function(el, i, ra) {
  timings.delay = i  * 2400;
  
  timings.duration = 5000;
  el.animate([
    {transform: 'rotateX(180deg)'},
    {transform:'rotateX(-180deg)'}
  ], timings);
  
  timings.duration = 7500;
  el.animate([
    {opacity: 1},
    {opacity: 0}
  ], timings);
  
  timings.duration = 10000;
 
});
```

```css
$background: #e45349;
$light: #efefff;

body {
  background: $background;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

div {
    display:     inline-block;
  
   position:   absolute;
  height:     inherit;
   text-align: center;
  width:      inherit;
  
  transform-style:     preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
   width:70px;
      height:50px;

      -moz-border-radius: 10px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
}



 
    
    .icon-one:before,
   .icon-one:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      border-bottom: 30px solid red;
      border-left: 10px solid transparent;
      border-right: 10px solid transparent;
      top: 30px;
      left: 20px;
      transform: rotate(-140deg);
    }
    
    .icon-four:before,
   .icon-four:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      border-bottom: 30px solid yellow;
      border-left: 10px solid transparent;
      border-right: 10px solid transparent;
      top: 30px;
      left: 20px;
      transform: rotate(-140deg);
    }
    
    
    
     
    .icon-three:before,
   .icon-three:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      border-bottom: 30px solid blue;
      border-left: 10px solid transparent;
      border-right: 10px solid transparent;
      top: 30px;
      left: 20px;
      transform: rotate(-140deg);
    }
    
    .icon-two:before,
   .icon-two:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      border-bottom: 30px solid green;
      border-left: 10px solid transparent;
      border-right: 10px solid transparent;
      top: 30px;
      left: 20px;
      transform: rotate(-140deg);
    }
.icon-one{background: red;}
.icon-two{background:  green;}
.icon-three{background: blue;}
.icon-four{background:  yellow;}
```

```html
<div  class="icon-one"><br>One</div>
<div class="icon-two"><br>Two</div>
<div  class="icon-three"><br>Three</div>
<div  class="icon-four"><br>Four</div>
```

and this

```css
.container {
  display:     inline-block;
  width:       64px;
  height:      64px;
  perspective: 700px;
}
.icon, .icon-one, .icon-two{
  position:   absolute;
  height:     inherit;
  width:      inherit;
  transition: all .5s;
  transform-style:     preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
   width:50px;
      height:50px;

}

/* ::: FACES */
.icon-one{background: red;}
.icon-two{background:  green;}

/* ::: SETUP FACES */
}
.icon-wrap .icon-one{transform: rotateX(180deg);}
.icon-wrap .icon-two{transform: rotateX(-180deg);}
/* ::: HOVER EFFECTS (Remove Automated for this to work) */

.icon-wrap:hover .icon{ transform: rotateX(180deg); }

/* ::: AUTOMATED EFFECTS */

.icon-wrap .icon{
  animation: icon-wrap 5s 1s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: icon-wrap 5s 1s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}



@keyframes icon-wrap {
  0% { transform: rotateX(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateX(180deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes icon-wrap {
  0% { transform: rotateX(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateX(180deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="container icon-wrap">
  <div class="icon">
    <div class="icon-one"> One</div>
    <div class="icon-two"> Two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See this:https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

And this:[How to Flip the div in time intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748875/how-to-flip-the-div-in-time-intervals)

Comment: Tried that already and saw that website. I have the flipping thing going with the transform perspective thing. The problem is how can i have it pause and play again without having any actions such as hover / etc? Like let it auto loop? Sorry it's a bit hard for me to explain but I have it live on my website on a viewport of iphone 5s in google chrome.

Comment: Just change the transition: 0.6s; time.

Comment: Very close. The problem now is I have 4 div's that I want to flip. And I want every single one of the divs to be start the flip from 180deg to 0 then 180 deg. While it has different interval or timing. So each take turn flipping

Comment: See this:https://www.solodev.com/blog/web-design/how-to-make-multiple-and-repeatable-css-animations.stml
and this https://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_multiple_elements_animate_method.htm

Comment: thanksman! i made a gif so I'll post it here to make it easier to see waht im saying visually. But these are very close to what I'm seeking for.

Comment: @RaymondShen try it now.